# Want a regex for validating Indian Vehicle Number Format?

Tags: java, regex, validation

Hello everyone here...

I need to build up a swing application related to vehicle registration and in which i want to do input the vehicle number of indian standard, like:

> MP 09 AB 1234
>
> AH 17 FT 2387
>
> UT 32 DR 6423
>
> DL 01 C AA 1111

More Specifically,

Please if any one can help me?
`DocumentFilter` type class can also help me.........

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Based on the [Wikipedia spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_India):

```
^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$
```

- The first two letters of the registration plate represent the State in which the vehicle is Registered.
- The next two digit numbers are the sequential number of a district. Due to heavy volume of vehicle registration, the numbers were given to the RTO offices of registration as well.
- The third part is a 4 digit number unique to each plate. A letter(s) is prefixed when the 4 digit number runs out and then two letters and so on.
- In some states (such as the union territory of Delhi, and previously in Gujarat and Bihar ) the initial 0 of the district code is omitted; thus Delhi district 2 numbers appear as DL 2 not DL 02.
- The National Capital Territory of Delhi has an additional code in the registration code: **DL 01 C AA 1111**

Comment: +1 for checking out the official specs, the egs in the q are not all scenarios.

Comment: Hey all here thank you very much, and alix your ans works perfectly as i needed.....but for this regex i can only checks the already input string, but what if i strict that regex during time of input in my textbox?? So that the user can't enter the anything wrong except the one which follows this format??    Actually i am talking to bound the input according to this regex....hope i am clear to you.......Will there is a way to do this?

Comment: @Asif: Back in the dark days before jQuery I used TMT Validator, it supports validations as you type, check http://www.massimocorner.com/libraries/validator/samples/custom_filters.htm. There might be a better jQuerish way though.

Comment: @Asif: To convert the regex to an "interactive mode" mode you can use atomic groups or just encapsulate each and every possible char inside a nested optional non-capturing group. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917998/regex-to-validate-smtp-responses for an example. One more thing, if you're doing this with Javascript make sure it supports the regex groups you're trying to use.

Comment: @AlixAxel This regex accepts "MH-01 FY 9090"  but not "MH-01-FY-9090'' ,how to make it accept hyphens and spaces both .

Comment: @AlixAxel: Was trying to understand `(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)?`
The second expression `(?: [A-Z]*)?` would match if there are 0 or more characters
So this would match DL 1  ABCDEF 1234.
Shouldn't we put it  `(?: [A-Z]{0,2})?` 
Please correct me if I am unable to understand to expression correctly.

Comment: Will it work for Javascript?

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
^[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{4}$
```

`^` means start of string 
`[A-Z]{2}` means 2 characters in the range of A through Z
`\s` means white space
`[0-9]{2}` means 2 characters in the range of 0 through 9
`\s` means white space
`[A-Z]{2}` means 2 characters in the range of A through Z
`\s` means white space
`[0-9]{4}` means 4 characters in the range of 0 through 9
`$` means end of string

Based on what you said in your question this should be a very broad check against proper format, but I have a feeling that there are more specific regulations on how the license plates are numbered. Let me know if there are additional constraints for the regex.

Answer (score 6):

Indian Vehicle number are like :

> **GJ 01 AA 1234** *or* **KA 08 J 9192**  *or* **(New Bharat Series)** like **22 BH 1234 AB** *or* **22 BH 1234 A**

**You Can validate using these 2 regular expressions:**

```
1) ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{4}$
2) ^[0-9]{2}BH[0-9]{4}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}$
```

**As per RTO rules:**

> **In RTO series Alphabet 'I' and 'O', 2 are excluded to avoid confusion with digits 0 or 1.**

Comment: The bharat series regex should be `^[0-9]{2}BH[0-9]{4}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}$`. I have seen cases where there is only one alphabet at the end. E.g. **22BH4928A**, this is a valid BH series number. See another sample in this tweet also https://twitter.com/satejp/status/1453291407217676295

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for number plate(VRN) then use following regex

```
^[A-Z|a-z]{2}\s?[0-9]{1,2}\s?[A-Z|a-z]{0,3}\s?[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Z]{2} [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{4}$
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_India

Looks like the format is a bit more complex than stated in your question...

Comment: yes it does, one space in between each group, see http://rubular.com/r/cgEeUKg5qX

Comment: Ahh my apologies. I've tried with JS and C# before to use spaces instead of \s but for some reason I didn't think that worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
AP-05-BJ-9353
TN-35-AB-638
MH-03-C-3843
```

Expression:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[-][0-9]{1,2}[-][A-Z]{1,2}[-][0-9]{3,4}$
```

Check the expression here: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

just check it out for whitespace only...

```
  function isValidNumber($Number){
         $pattern = "^[a-zA-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{4}$";
         if (eregi($pattern, $Number)){
            return true;
         }
         else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing the second pair of letters.

Comment: Hey all here thank you very much, your ans works perfectly as i needed.....but for this regex i can only checks the already entered string, but what if i strict that user according to this regex during time of input in my textbox?? So that the user can't enter the anything wrong except the one which follows this format??    Actually i am talking to bound the input according to this regex....hope i am clear to you.......Will there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Say for example if the user already entered a value like:

```
DL
```

then the textbox did not take the next input any other than a integer or one more char as.....

```
DL C
```

from here user can only enter a integer value............

So, in short what i want to do is to take the input only like that regex given by Alix

Based on the [Wikipedia Specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_India)

```
^[A-Z]{2}[ -][0-9]{1,2}(?: [A-Z])?(?: [A-Z]*)? [0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

-(BOOL) validateVehicleRegNumber:(NSString *)strNumber
{
    //Example MH14DA8904

```
    NSString *validReg = @"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", validReg];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:strNumber];
```

}

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: You got this from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[A-Z]{1,2}\s[0-9]{1,4}$
```

The above regex will work for the following types

DL 01 AA 1111

DL 0 AA 1111

DL 1 A 1111

DL 0 A 11

DL 01 AA 111

Answer (score 0):

```
//DL 01 C AA 1234
^[A-Z]{2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ -]{0,1}(?:[A-Z])[ -]{0,1}[A-Z]{1,2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}$

//MH 15 AA 1234
^[A-Z]{2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ -]{0,1}[A-Z]{1,2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}$

MVA 1234
^[A-Z]{3}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}$

//MH 15 8008
^[A-Z]{2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}$
```

with or without space :)

Comment: This is a very clever answer. Could you possibly add a little more information about how and why it works? Doing so will make this more useful to others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for number plate in substring then use the following regex

```
.*?([A-Za-z]{2})(\d{2})([A-Za-z]{2})(\d{4}).*?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to verify the number by state RTO and number by Central (BH Series)
try this :

```
    public static boolean validateNumberPlate(EditText numberPlate){
    final Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}[\\\\ -]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\\\\ -]{0,1}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}[\\\\ -]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$");   // for all states
    final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{2}[\\\\ -]{0,1}BH[\\\\ -]{0,1}[0-9]{4}[\\\\ -]{0,1}[A-HJ-NP-Z]{1,2}$");   // for BH Series

    return (pattern1.matcher(numberPlate.getText().toString().trim()).matches() || pattern2.matcher(numberPlate.getText().toString().trim()).matches());
}
```

> First Pattern is for the State RTO (Eg. RJ 00 XX 0000).

> Second pattern is for BH Series (Eg. 00 BH 0000 XX).