# want a function for validating French vehicle number format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a function that can check when typing plate registration in the input fields before the plate is a French plate

The format for french plate is : **AA - 123 - AA**

• [i found this question but i dont know how i can use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386300/want-a-regex-for-validating-indian-vehicle-number-format)

• [Wikipedia spec for french vehicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_France)

• [For example i need similary like this](http://www.plaqueimmatriculation-24h.com/plaque-siv?type=auto)

**i would like, When i typing for example : 12 I can't go further to the plate because there is an error etc.**

Thx for any help

Comment: You know there are many possible formats for French plates (some people have old cars) ? And many people have exotic plates. You'd better only check it's a not empty string.

Comment: @dystroy yes i know, but i make for new plate only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following for new not exotic French plates.

**HTML :**

```
<input id=myInputId>
```

**Javascript :**

```
var myString = document.getElementById('myInputId').value;
var isPlateOK = /^[A-Z]{2} ?- ?\d{3} ?- ?[A-Z]{2}$/.test(myString);
```

Notes :

- "A" is OK but not "a". If you want to allow lowercase, change `[A-Z]` to `[A-Za-z]`
- spaces are optional. If you want them to be mandatory, remove the `?`

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) about regular expressions in JavaScript.

---

To prevent inputs as soon as the value starts to be invalid, a different approach has to be taken :

```
function check(s) { // checks s is a plate id or the start of a plate id
    var toks = s.split('-');
    //console.log(toks);
    switch(toks.length){
        case 3:
        if (!/^[A-Z]{0,2}$/.test(toks[2].trim())) return false;
        case 2:
        if (!/^\d{0,3}$/.test(toks[1].trim())) return false;
        case 1:
        return /^[A-Z]{0,2}$/.test(toks[0].trim());
        default:
        return false;
    }  
}
var oldvalue = '';
$('#plates').keyup(function(){
    if (!check(this.value)) {
        this.value = oldvalue;
    } else {
        oldvalue = this.value;
    }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4tQ4/)

Comment: i dont know how i can use that... :$

Comment: @artSx Is it clearer now ?

Comment: i know this jsFiddle is wrong, but i dont know how i can use you're js. http://jsfiddle.net/vrnQ3/
i think is clear what i want with this fiddle.

Comment: [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6f6/).

Comment: Please don't comment in French here : this QA isn't just for you but for other coders too. But what you ask is very different from your initial question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, thin I thought I was well explained to my request with an example of what I wanted with the link

Comment: Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hRLuN/) ?

Comment: yes! but I'll be a bit of a perfectionist, is that it is possible that the "-" will add automatically, and it is directly capitalized if they ever tap in small case that doesn't validate, it may not understand 
PS : i love you.

Comment: yes, that's possible, but I won't do it : each time you change the requirement a different route has to be taken and I'm not paid to write your whole program. I'll just show you how to automatically change to uppercase : http://jsfiddle.net/MbQRJ/

Answer (score 2):

French plates don't contains `I`, `O` and `U`, and also not `000`, so the regex is:

```
^[A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*-\s*(?:00[1-9]|[0-9]{3})\s*-\s*[A-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

In our EU system for validating vehicle registration plates in EU countries, we use this script to create and maintain the regular expressions for an EU country. In Belgium the customer must also select a kind of plate : BE (default), EU or CD.

Script example Netherlands :

```
var d = '[0-9]';
var s = '[A-Z]';
var o = '-';
// var p = '\\.';
var t1 = s + s + o + d + d + o + d + d; // AA-99-99
var t2 = d + d + o + s + s + o + d + d; // 99-AA-99
var t3 = s + s + o + d + d + o + s + s; // AA-99-99
var t4 = s + s + o + s + s + o + d + d; // AA-AA-AA
var t5 = d + d + o + s + s + o + s + s; // 99-AA-AA
var t6 = d + d + o + s + s + s + o + d; // 99-AAA-9
var t7 = s + s + o + d + d + d + o + s; // AA-999-A
var t8 = s + o + d + d + d + o + s + s; // A-999-AA
var t9 = d + o + s + s + s + o + d + d; // 9-AAA-99
var string = {'DEFAULT-NL' : '^((' + t1 + ')|(' + t2 + ')|(' + t3 + ')|(' + t4 + ')|(' + t5 + ')|(' + t6 + ')|( ' + t7 + ')|(' + t8 + ')|(' + t9 + '))$'}[id];
return new RegExp(string);
```

Comment: How do i use this on a onchange function?